# Exporting ADC data to excel

Tags: arduino-uno

Do I need third party s/w to export to a spreadsheet? I have built a heat flux sensor meter and wish to log my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way of getting the data from the Arduino to the PC. There's a number of ways of doing it depending on what resources you have available.

- Through serial as CSV

This entails printing the data to the serial port in CSV format then using some software on the PC to capture that and save it to a file. That could be as simple as a good terminal emulator that provides "capture to file" or similar, or you could write your own program in your favourite programming language.  This method is essentially free.

- To an SD card

Writing the data as a CSV file onto an SD card directly attached to the Arduino can be quite convenient. It means you can then just take the SD card with the data on it and slip it into your computer to import the data as you would with any other file.  It needs an SD card shield or breakout board attaching to the Arduino

- Through the network

If your Arduino has a network connection of some form (WiFi shield, Ethernet shield, etc) you could POST the data to a web page running on your PC and store it in a CSV file for later importing. Probably the most expensive option but it does mean you can do things with the data "live" as it comes in.

Comment: Just note that Excel sometimes expect a `;` instead of a `,` inside a CSV file (depending on the locale settings of Windows)

Comment: If only they kept hyper terminal in WIN 7 :(

Comment: @eggroll Why? HT was shite.

Comment: True, but it offered a quick and dirty platform for what I needed. My S/W guy is writing the GUI, but I wanted to do some preliminary work and HT is easy for us H/W guys, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Use tabs to separate columns of data, and newlines between each row. 
Then you can copy the serial output, and paste it into Excel.